# Does the arrival of vehicle on a specified point of a road follow a poisson process?

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

I am asking about a poisson with the same rate but different serving time, because a point in a road have a maximum capacity of letting a number of cars pass through it, but in the same time the speed of the vehicles is variable so if a car is slow it is going to take a longer serving time, while on the other hand if a car is fast it will take smaller amount. so should i take into account only the maximum serving time, when the cars are at their fastest velocity, or this example doesn't actually follow a poisson process.

Comment: Let $X_t$ denotes the number of cars driving over the specific point on $[0,t]$, where $t$ is the number of hours since the counting began. I wouldn't expect $X_t$ to follow a Poisson distribution as the number of expected number of arrivals per unit of time isn't constant. (You expect more cars during the day than at night.) It would be more plausible to mode $X_t$ as a $\text{Poisson}\left(\int_0^t\lambda(x)\mathrm{d}x \right)$ random variable where $\lambda(t)$ is a sinusoidal function with period $24$.

Comment: Well in my case the rate is known for each day the week, what i am suspecting is that the serving time is the variable.